# Upload image from client to server using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, image-uploading

I'm using the jquery cropbox plugin:
https://github.com/hongkhanh/cropbox
With this source code:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/t8bdodvj

This plugin crops the image, and generates a new one on the client side.
The cropbox api provides 2 methods for accessing the image:
1) getDataURL()
2) getBlob()

My question is, how can I upload the new generated image from the client side to the server, with PHP:
- using getDataURL()?
- using getBlob()?

Code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Crop Box</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        .container
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10%; left: 10%; right: 0; bottom: 0;
        }
        .action
        {
            width: 400px;
            height: 30px;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }
        .cropped>img
        {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../cropbox.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="imageBox">
        <div class="thumbBox"></div>
        <div class="spinner" style="display: none">Loading...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
        <input type="file" id="file" style="float:left; width: 250px">
        <input type="button" id="btnCrop" value="Crop" style="float: right">
        <input type="button" id="btnZoomIn" value="+" style="float: right">
        <input type="button" id="btnZoomOut" value="-" style="float: right">
    </div>
    <div class="cropped">

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        var options =
        {
            thumbBox: '.thumbBox',
            spinner: '.spinner',
            imgSrc: 'avatar.png'
        }
        var cropper;
        $('#file').on('change', function(){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                options.imgSrc = e.target.result;
                cropper = $('.imageBox').cropbox(options);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            this.files = [];
        })
        $('#btnCrop').on('click', function(){
            var img = cropper.getDataURL()
            $('.cropped').append('<img src="'+img+'">');
        })
        $('#btnZoomIn').on('click', function(){
            cropper.zoomIn();
        })
        $('#btnZoomOut').on('click', function(){
            cropper.zoomOut();
        })
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.imageBox
{
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor:move;
}

.imageBox .thumbBox
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
}

.imageBox .spinner
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 400px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

JS

```
/**
 * Created by ezgoing on 14/9/2014.
 */

"use strict";
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {
    var cropbox = function(options, el){
        var el = el || $(options.imageBox),
            obj =
            {
                state : {},
                ratio : 1,
                options : options,
                imageBox : el,
                thumbBox : el.find(options.thumbBox),
                spinner : el.find(options.spinner),
                image : new Image(),
                getDataURL: function ()
                {
                    var width = this.thumbBox.width(),
                        height = this.thumbBox.height(),
                        canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
                        dim = el.css('background-position').split(' '),
                        size = el.css('background-size').split(' '),
                        dx = parseInt(dim[0]) - el.width()/2 + width/2,
                        dy = parseInt(dim[1]) - el.height()/2 + height/2,
                        dw = parseInt(size[0]),
                        dh = parseInt(size[1]),
                        sh = parseInt(this.image.height),
                        sw = parseInt(this.image.width);

                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
                    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
                    var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    return imageData;
                },
                getBlob: function()
                {
                    var imageData = this.getDataURL();
                    var b64 = imageData.replace('data:image/png;base64,','');
                    var binary = atob(b64);
                    var array = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
                        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
                    }
                    return  new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});
                },
                zoomIn: function ()
                {
                    this.ratio*=1.1;
                    setBackground();
                },
                zoomOut: function ()
                {
                    this.ratio*=0.9;
                    setBackground();
                }
            },
            setBackground = function()
            {
                var w =  parseInt(obj.image.width)*obj.ratio;
                var h =  parseInt(obj.image.height)*obj.ratio;

                var pw = (el.width() - w) / 2;
                var ph = (el.height() - h) / 2;

                el.css({
                    'background-image': 'url(' + obj.image.src + ')',
                    'background-size': w +'px ' + h + 'px',
                    'background-position': pw + 'px ' + ph + 'px',
                    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'});
            },
            imgMouseDown = function(e)
            {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                obj.state.dragable = true;
                obj.state.mouseX = e.clientX;
                obj.state.mouseY = e.clientY;
            },
            imgMouseMove = function(e)
            {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                if (obj.state.dragable)
                {
                    var x = e.clientX - obj.state.mouseX;
                    var y = e.clientY - obj.state.mouseY;

                    var bg = el.css('background-position').split(' ');

                    var bgX = x + parseInt(bg[0]);
                    var bgY = y + parseInt(bg[1]);

                    el.css('background-position', bgX +'px ' + bgY + 'px');

                    obj.state.mouseX = e.clientX;
                    obj.state.mouseY = e.clientY;
                }
            },
            imgMouseUp = function(e)
            {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                obj.state.dragable = false;
            },
            zoomImage = function(e)
            {
                e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0 ? obj.ratio*=1.1 : obj.ratio*=0.9;
                setBackground();
            }

        obj.spinner.show();
        obj.image.onload = function() {
            obj.spinner.hide();
            setBackground();

            el.bind('mousedown', imgMouseDown);
            el.bind('mousemove', imgMouseMove);
            $(window).bind('mouseup', imgMouseUp);
            el.bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', zoomImage);
        };
        obj.image.src = options.imgSrc;
        el.on('remove', function(){$(window).unbind('mouseup', imgMouseUp)});

        return obj;
    };

    jQuery.fn.cropbox = function(options){
        return new cropbox(options, this);
    };
}));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To the person who downvoted.. anything wrong with the question?

Comment: you don't show your code. also if you have two options, why not just try them?

Comment: your question has to be valid even if all the links become unavailable, os at least the most important part of the code has to be pasted into the question.

Comment: Thks for the tip. Fixed the question.